# QGIS 3.4.4 Issue when manually modifying values in graduated style

Tags: qgis, style

In Win10, QGIS 3.4.4. In a polygon layer, I go to properties->Style->Graduated->classify, and I want to manually modify values for each symbol displayed. But once I modify values manually and click "accept", the values are not the ones I wanted, and there's no way I can do it without QGIS doing something different. See screenshots:
[image]

I've tried to solve it re-installing QGIS, but the problem remains. It is also strange that this problem is not happening in another computer I have with the same QGIS version, so I am wondering if there's something I need to adjust in my computer.

It is annoying that I cannot input the values I want for each symbol, and I need to go back to QGIS 2.18 everytime I have this issue, and my wish is to work with QGIS 3.4.

Comment: A hunch: could your qgis be set to a locale which uses comma as the decimal separator?

Comment: Hi. Thanks but it's not the case. I also thought that could be the reason and tried to modify my local setting, use commas instead of points, but nothing changes. Actually if you look at the image, I just change a number, no touching points, and everything gets messed up. Any other idea... ?